# Istioctl to override a setting that includes \

Tags: set, upgrade

Every time I am trying the following command I am getting getting the error:

**Error:**

```
spec.selector: Invalid value: "topology.istio.io\"\\network\"": name part must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character
```

**Command:**

```
istioctl install -f  $CFG_FOLDER/istio-eastwestgateway-operator.yaml \
--set revision=$ISTIO_REV \
--set components.ingressGateways[0].name=istio-$EW_GW_NAME \
--set components.ingressGateways[0].label.istio=$EW_GW_NAME \
--set components.ingressGateways[0].label.app=istio-$EW_GW_NAME \
--set "components.ingressGateways[0].label.topology\.istio\.io/network"=$NETWORK \
--set components.ingressGateways[0].k8s.env[name:ISTIO_META_REQUESTED_NETWORK_VIEW].value=$NETWORK \
--set values.global.network=$NETWORK
```

I am trying to istio upgrade of the east-west gateway on a multicluster while setting the parameters dynamically.